# XeTeX/mathspec, more than one math digits font

Tags: math-mode, xetex, fontspec, mathspec

When using the mathspec package, is it possible to have more than one math digits font in different places in the same document.

Mostly, I want the font for my math digits to be the same as my main text font, but at some places I use Eastern Arabic numerals within the math environment, so I want to be able to switch to a font that has these unicode characters. (Yes, I could choose a font that has these defined as my main text font, but that is not the optimal solution at the moment.)

Here is a minimal example, which helps explain what I am trying to do.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Junicode}

\setmathsfont(Digits){Junicode} % XITS Math
\setmathsfont(Symbols){XITS Math}
\setmathsfont(Latin){Junicode}
\setmathrm{Junicode}

\def\offsetdigits#1{%
\xoffset{#1}0%
\xoffset{#1}1%
\xoffset{#1}2%
\xoffset{#1}3%
\xoffset{#1}4%
\xoffset{#1}5%
\xoffset{#1}6%
\xoffset{#1}7%
\xoffset{#1}8%
\xoffset{#1}9}
\def\xoffset#1#2{%
\XeTeXmathcodenum`#2=\numexpr\XeTeXmathcodenum`#2-`0+#1\relax}


\begin{document}

I want the digits in my math environment to be the same as those in my text, 
for example, 44{\textdegree} and $\frac{\pi}{\sin 44 \text{\textdegree}}$.

But at other points in the document, I want to be able to switch to a different 
font so that I can have some Eastern Arabic digits in the math environment; for 
example {\offsetdigits{"0660}$\frac{2}{5}$}. The numbers in this fraction will 
only appear if we switch Junicode with XITS Math in the \verb|\setmathsfont(Digits)
{Junicode}| line in the preamble. 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Due to the many `preamble-only` restrictions customary in LaTeX<sup>(1)</sup>, and for which `mathspec` is no exception<sup>(2)</sup>, one can not just do a natural `\setmathsfont{Digits}{xits-math.otf}` at the desired location in the document body.

<sup>(1)</sup> for example, codeline 583 in File r: ltfssdcl.dtx Date: 2011/05/08 Version v3.0n of the Sources of LaTeX2e: \@onlypreamble\DeclareMathSymbol

<sup>(2)</sup> it contains also many \@onlypreamble, admittedly for the case at hand, those already in the kernel of LaTeX are the main obstacle to a *quick*, *local* soution.

`mathspec` has no interface for math versions, so some hacking is necessary.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[MnSymbol]{mathspec}

\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Junicode}

\makeatletter
\setmathsfont(Digits){xits-math.otf}     % temporary declaration
\edef\SavedFontName{\eu@Digitsmathsfont}
\makeatother

\setmathsfont(Digits){Junicode} 
\setmathsfont(Symbols){XITS Math}
\setmathsfont(Latin){Junicode}
\setmathrm{Junicode}

%%% \setmathsfont(Digits){Baskerville}   % testing at home 
%%% \setmathsfont(Symbols){xits-math.otf}

\makeatletter
\DeclareMathVersion{XITSdigits}
\SetSymbolFont{\eu@DigitsArabic@symfont}
        {XITSdigits} {EU1} {\SavedFontName} {m} {n}
\makeatother

\def\offsetdigits#1{%
\xoffset{#1}0%
\xoffset{#1}1%
\xoffset{#1}2%
\xoffset{#1}3%
\xoffset{#1}4%
\xoffset{#1}5%
\xoffset{#1}6%
\xoffset{#1}7%
\xoffset{#1}8%
\xoffset{#1}9}
\def\xoffset#1#2{%
\XeTeXmathcodenum`#2=\numexpr\XeTeXmathcodenum`#2-`0+#1\relax}

\begin{document}

I want the digits in my math environment to be the same as those in my text, 
for example, 44{\textdegree} and $\frac{\pi}{\sin 44 \text{\textdegree}}$.


\mathversion{XITSdigits}

But at other points in the document, I want to be able to switch to a different 
font so that I can have some Eastern Arabic digits in the math environment; for 
example {\offsetdigits{"0660}$\frac{2}{5}$}. The numbers in this fraction will 
only appear if we switch Junicode with XITS Math in the 
\verb|\setmathsfont(Digits){Junicode}| line in the preamble. 

\end{document}
```